# Highcharts: convert columns to stacked column in multiple axis chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stacked-chart, multiple-axes

I want to use [combo-multiple-axis chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) but i want to convert "columns" to "stacked columns" because one of my "y value serie" is the [sum of 3 data series](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) and i want to show that change on my chart too.

I am so new with javascript and coding but i guess there might be a way to add sub-data series to a primary data serie.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn on [stacking on the columns](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking) and then add multiple series of type `column` and this will just work.

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},
```

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zE2Th/).

Comment: thank you sooooo much. this is going to be very helpful for my work :)